# Copy multiple values from from a single column

Tags: excel

Excel sheet has values like y = 498.7x - 11.323 in a column. I want to copy "498.7" and "-11.323" values in different column in same sheet. Can we do that?

Comment: try exploring the `mid()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my below screenshot you can try `FILTERXML()` formula.

<kbd>B1</kbd>=

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1,"x","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()=1]")," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))*1
```

<kbd>C1</kbd>=

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1,"x","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

[image]